# Error using Artifactory Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I am trying to deploy my Jenkins generated artifacts into Artifactory using the `Artifactory plugin`. However, I get the following error:

```
For pattern: my_path/artifact_name.tar.gz 1 artifacts were found
Deploying artifact: http://server_name:8081/artifactory/build_artifacts/artifact_name.tar.gz
ERROR: remote file operation failed: /workspace/in/slave/node at hudson.remoting.Channel@56f0631:slave_node: java.io.IOException: Remote call on slave_node failed
java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: /workspace/in/slave/node at hudson.remoting.Channel@56f0631:slave_node: java.io.IOException: Remote call on slave_node failed
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:987)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:969)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer.deploy(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:81)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator$1.tearDown(ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator.java:346)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:173)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on slave_node failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:786)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:980)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.InetAddress
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.PreemptiveHttpClient.execute(PreemptiveHttpClient.java:89)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getVersion(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:136)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.getArtifactoryVersion(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:702)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.tryChecksumDeploy(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:591)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:559)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:282)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.deploy(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:206)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:178)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:122)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2691)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to ffuas4eng01(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1413)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:221)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:778)
    ... 10 more
```

The repository on Artifactory is called `build_artifacts`. And I have ensured that the Jenkins user for Artifactory (which is `admin`) has the deploy permissions into it. The `http url` also does not give any information on the generated artifact. What is going wrong with my set-up?

Another piece of information that would be important is my Jenkins configuration - I have a master node and a slave node. The build artifacts are generated on the slave node.

On clicking the deploying artifact link, I get the following on my display:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "File not found."
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Seems like your Artifactory instance might be unreachable from the slave node - can you try accessing it directly from the slave?

Comment: There are no artifacts as of yet in Artifactory repository. What does it mean to try to access from slave?

Comment: run `curl http://server_name:8080/artifactory/api/system/ping` from the slave -- does it return a response?

Comment: In any case, I have the option that the artifacts are archived after each build. This being the case, is there a possiblity to have master copy the artifacts to Artifactory?

Comment: I ran the curl command and I got the response as `OK`

Comment: You should use the [Jenkins plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+%28Hudson%29+Artifactory+Plug-in) - will make your life easier

Comment: Did you run `curl` from your own machine or from the slave node? it's pretty apparent there's some communication issue between the slave and the Artifactory instance from the stack trace

Comment: I ran the curl from the slave node and got the response as OK. Apparently there are two plugins - Artifactory plugin and Jenkins (Hudson) Artifactory plugin. I used the former. Let me try with the latter next. I am not sure how to go about debugging the communication issue between Artifactory and slave.

Comment: Trying the official one (the one I linked) is probably a good idea - if `curl` succeeds then it's probably related to Jenkins` own configuration

Comment: I think they are both the same plugins on Jenkins. I cannot find the name of the other plugin and Jenkins documentation tells me they are the same.

Comment: are you using the same JVM version on both the master and slave?

Comment: Yes, the JVM versions on both machines are the same.